# How to solve CLEANRBT SPOJ with dynamic programming and bitmasking?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search

Problem Link : [CLEANRBT](https://www.spoj.com/problems/CLEANRBT/) . I read [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-algorithmic-approach-to-solve-the-problem-Cleaning-robots-CLEANRBT-on-SPOJ) that problem can be solved by first finding all distances between each pair of dirty cells using BFS .That part i understood.

Now we need to find answer for each of the case where final position of the robot will be the i'th dirty cell and i we need to take minimum for all of them .I didn't understood how to do that .

Comment: Please don't leave essential information behind a link. On StackOverflow the question should be self-contained.